# How to pass a spreadsheet ID or URL as a parameter to a function in apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've seen this done on youtube several times, but for some reason, I receive this error message:
Exception: Invalid argument: id

I'm trying to pass a spreadsheet URL or ID from one function (run) as a parameter to another function (pasteDailyTotals).  I've provided the code below for reference:

```
function pasteDailyTotals(sourceID) {

  //Source info
  var sourceS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
}

function run(){

  pasteDailyTotals("14TJ9n_hRH_2sfUr7DKljRNnLoJ9UKUD1aMeR-f5pQig");
}
```

Comment: Well, is it a valid id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Assuming the `id` is correct, the issue must be that you don't execute the correct function.

By default, the first function defined in the script is selected for execution which `pasteDailyTotals`. If you execute the latter, `sourceID` won't be defined and hence the error you are getting.

**Solution:**

You can either switch the position of the functions, put the definition of `run` above `pasteDailyTotals` or simply select `run` to be executed:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I feel like such a novice because I am such a novice.  Makes total sense.